# What is 'originator' tag in nifti file?

Tags: matlab, nifti

I've a clear question. what is the 'originator' tag in nifti file? and how to must calculate this tag value?

Comment: There is no Matlab code here, why the Matlab tag?

Comment: your right. i use different matlab function to read nifti file. do you know what is the originator tag?

Answer (score 0):

> what is the 'originator' tag in nifti file?

I'm going to assume that you're using  [Tools for NIfTI and ANALYZE image](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image), which has tools to handle NIfTI images using MATLAB. I'm assuming this because I know that when you use the `load_nii()` function, it gives you a variable that has an 'originator tag' in its header.

In this context, the `nii.hdr.hist.originator` field represents the origin coordinates of the voxels, expressed in sform or qform, as it's clarified in the comments of the tools' [File Exchange page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image).

> and how to must calculate this tag value?

From what I understand, the `originator` field is filled correctly when you use `load_nii()` or `make_nii()`, so you don't actually calculate it.